# Random-access container for strings in python?

Tags: python, performance, random-access

I manipulate with indexed instances (say, music tracks) and have to lookup object's name by its index (int->string). Dicts are too slow (I have about 10M objects). Memory is not a problem, so the most convinient solution would be to create a random-access array of strings from csv file with names.

However, I have failed to make this in python -- I got an error that 0-dim arrays (strings) couldn't be indexed. What's the native python way to create random access container for strings?

Comment: Are the indices consecutive from `0` to `n-1`?  If so, use a list.  That won't be a whole lot faster than a dict, but it will be faster.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a database. Have you looked into [`sqlite`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)?

Comment: @Tim: probably better if the list isn't completely static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember, dictionaries in Python have O(1) average access time, but lists will definitely be faster. If your indices are not very sparse, you can try something like this:

```
reader = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')] # Replace it with your CSV reader.

# First, fill a dictionary:
text_dict = {}
for index, text in reader:
    text_dict[index] = text

# Then create a sufficiently large list:
max_index = max(text_dict.iterkeys())
texts = [None] * (max_index + 1)

# And fill it:
for index, text in text_dict.iteritems():
    texts[index] = text

print texts
# prints: [None, 'a', 'b']
print texts[1]
# prints: a
```

Comment: Lists are O(1) for random access, and are perfectly fine for the job. Dicts have O(1) reads, too, but the constant is far higher.

Comment: @senderle, 9000 is right. That question/answer is not the same. That is asking about finding if something is contained in a dict/list while we are talking up looking up a specific key in a dictionary vs. looking up a specific index in a list. For this purpose, dicts have to calculate the hash while lists just go to the correct index. Hashing takes more time.

Comment: @Justin, yeah sorry I deleted that comment when I realized I had misread the latter post.

Comment: you're right, lists work perfectly! Degrees better than dicts in my case. I missed the fact lists in Python has O(1) random access complexity, shame on me.